# How do i fill the entire UIScrollView that i placed inside a UITableCell using swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, ios8

I'm making an app that shows a timetable for a festival. The festival has multiple stages with each multiple bands. My idea was to make a TableView with rows for each stage. Then in that row i wanted to place multiple buttons, each representing a band. I use buttons because i want a followup page on a band/artist.

What i got so far is this: I have a TableView with 3 rows. I filled the rows with only 1 button to check if it scrolls allright. The button fills the whole scrollview. the scrollview is 5 times longer then the  tablecell.

My problem is: when i scroll, everything that comes after the first look is blank. while it's supposed to be filled with the green button.

My code:

```
class TimeTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
//@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
//var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    //cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    var scrollview = UIScrollView(frame: cell.bounds)
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cell.bounds.width * 5, cell.bounds.height)
    scrollview.pagingEnabled = false

    var button = UIButton()

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollview.frame.size.width, height: scrollview.frame.size.height)
    //x: 0, y: 0, width:image.size.width, height:scrollView.frame.size.height

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("bladiebladiebla juj een button in een scrollview in een table cell, nu nog een aantal buttons", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    //var label = UILabel(frame: scrollview.bounds)
    //label.text = "bladiebladiebla juj een label in een scrollview in een table cell, nu nog een aantal buttons"

    scrollview.addSubview(button)

    cell.contentView.addSubview(scrollview)

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemeted your code and In that do some changes like this...

At start Scrollview doesn't have proper cell height as i defind in xib is 80 but Scrollview height show around 50

I have did scrollview.removeFromSuperView because when i come back after didSelceting cell it show proper cell size 80 and give fixed scroll height  as cell height..

```
    //change by me..
    var scrollview = UIScrollView()
 ----------------------------------------------
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell
  {
      var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    //cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    //change by me..
    scrollview.removeFromSuperview()
    scrollview = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 80))
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cell.frame.size.width * 5, cell.frame.size.height)
    scrollview.pagingEnabled = false

    var button = UIButton()

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollview.frame.size.width, height: scrollview.frame.size.height)
    //x: 0, y: 0, width:image.size.width, height:scrollView.frame.size.height

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("bladiebladiebla juj een button in een scrollview in een table cell, nu nog een aantal buttons", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    //var label = UILabel(frame: scrollview.bounds)
    //label.text = "bladiebladiebla juj een label in een scrollview in een table cell, nu nog een aantal buttons"
    var button1 = UIButton()

    button1.frame = CGRect(x: button.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: scrollview.frame.size.width, height: scrollview.frame.size.height)
    //x: 0, y: 0, width:image.size.width, height:scrollView.frame.size.height

    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    button1.setTitle("bladiebladiebla juj een button in een scrollview in een table cell, nu nog een aantal buttons", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    //var label = UILabel(frame: scrollview.bounds)
    //label.text = "bladiebladiebla juj een label in een scrollview in een table cell, nu nog een aantal buttons"

    scrollview.addSubview(button)
    scrollview.addSubview(button1)

    cell.contentView.addSubview(scrollview)
     return cell

  }
```